# P values from HSD.test

Tags: r, statistics, anova, p-value, posthoc

I am using the `HSD.test` function from the `agricolae` package in `R` to conduct a TukeyHSD post hoc test. The function works fine except I'm not sure where the p values are hidden. The letters in `groups` denote significance, but where are the actual p values? Thank you

```
library(agricolae)
data(sweetpotato)
model<-aov(yield~virus, data=sweetpotato)
out <- HSD.test(model,"virus", group=TRUE,console=TRUE,
main="Yield of sweetpotato\nDealt with different virus")



Study: Yield of sweetpotato
Dealt with different virus

HSD Test for yield 

Mean Square Error:  22.48917 

virus,  means

      yield      std r  Min  Max
cc 24.40000 3.609709 3 21.7 28.5
fc 12.86667 2.159475 3 10.6 14.9
ff 36.33333 7.333030 3 28.0 41.8
oo 36.90000 4.300000 3 32.1 40.4

Alpha: 0.05 ; DF Error: 8 
Critical Value of Studentized Range: 4.52881 

Minimun Significant Difference: 12.39967 

Treatments with the same letter are not significantly different.

      yield groups
oo 36.90000      a
ff 36.33333     ab
cc 24.40000     bc
fc 12.86667      c
```

Comment: @PoGibas Surely it must or how would the letters be determined?

Comment: Good question. Not sure how to do it using that command. Try `TukeyHSD(model)` which is a base R command. This gives you p values (adjusted) for pairwise comparisons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing `group` to `FALSE` returns the comparisons instead of the compact letter display.

```
out = HSD.test(model, "virus", group = FALSE)
print(out$comparison)

         difference pvalue signif.         LCL         UCL
cc - fc  11.5333333 0.0686       .  -0.8663365  23.9330031
cc - ff -11.9333333 0.0592       . -24.3330031   0.4663365
cc - oo -12.5000000 0.0482       * -24.8996698  -0.1003302
fc - ff -23.4666667 0.0014      ** -35.8663365 -11.0669969
fc - oo -24.0333333 0.0012      ** -36.4330031 -11.6336635
ff - oo  -0.5666667 0.9988         -12.9663365  11.8330031
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. This is just what I need.

Comment: Using the argument  `console=TRUE `  changes how the output is shown

Comment: The groups are computed using the function `orderPvalue`. I ran `body(orderPvalue)` to see how the group assignments are made, because I have treatments being assigned to completely different groups despite a p-value well above `alpha`. The code is not very clear to me.